# convert an array of objects to an object based on a given key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am new to Javascript.

I need to write a function to covert an array of objects to an object with a given key.

The input is like this

```
convert([{id: 1, value: 'abc'}, {id: 2, value: 'xyz'}], 'id')
```

and output needs to be like this

```
{
    '1': {id: 1, value: 'abc'},
    '2': {id: 2, value: 'xyz'}
}
```

I have tried the below code.

When I am trying this directly in console it seems it is working.

```js
var arr = [{ id: 1, name: 'John', role: 'Developer'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Jane', role: 'Lead'},
    { id: 3, name: 'Robbie', role: 'QA'}];

let res = arr.reduce((prev, current) => {
  prev[current.v] = current;
  return prev;
}, {})

console.log(res)
```

But, when I am trying do it from the function it is not working.

```
function f(k, v) {
  //console.log(k);              
  k.reduce((prev, current) => {
    prev[current.v] = current;
    return prev;
    console.log(prev)
  }, {})
}

f(arr, 'role');
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple. Why complicating by reduce and etc.,

```js
function convert(arr, key) {
  output = {};
  arr.forEach(function(item) {
    output[item[key]] = item;
  })
  console.log(output)
  return output
}

convert([{id: 1, value: 'abc'}, {id: 2, value: 'xyz'}], 'id')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cvydtL7p/

Comment: [How do I create a runnable Stack Snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 2):

You could take a dunctional approach by mapping an assigning new object.

```js
function convert(array, key) {
    return Object.assign(...array.map(o => ({ [o[key]]: o })));
}


console.log(convert([{ id: 1, value: 'abc' }, { id: 2, value: 'xyz' }], 'id'))
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for me:

```
function convert(obj, key) {
    var newObj = {};
    obj.forEach(element => {
        newObj[element[key]] = element;
    });
    return newObj;
}

var newObj = convert([{id: 1, value: 'abc'}, {id: 2, value: 'xyz'}], 'id');

console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but you need nested bracket notation to get to the proper key name, eg

```
prev[current[v]]
```

or

```
a[item[keyName]] // as in code below
```

```js
const convert = (arr, keyName) => arr.reduce((a, item) => {
  a[item[keyName]] = item;
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(
  convert([{id: 1, value: 'abc'}, {id: 2, value: 'xyz'}], 'id')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty much working, the only errors are to use bracket notation to access a variable key; for example:

`obj[v]` will evaluate to `obj.id` if `v` was `id`

The other error is that you are simply missing to `return` from your function, resulting in an `undefined` result

```js
var arr = [{ id: 1, name: 'John', role: 'Developer'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Jane', role: 'Lead'},
    { id: 3, name: 'Robbie', role: 'QA'}];


function f(k, v) {
  //console.log(k);              
  return k.reduce((prev, current) => {
    prev[current[v]] = current;
    return prev;
  }, {})
}

console.log(f(arr, 'role'));
```

Also note that nothing after `return` will happen, so the `console.log` line in your reducer should be before that, otherwise it's ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` and `spread` like this:

```js
var arr = [{id: 1, value: 'abc'}, {id: 2, value: 'xyz'}];

const res = arr.reduce((total, curr) => {
  return {...total, [curr.id]: curr };
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

refs: 
[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
[Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)